# SystemExit: 2 error when calling parse_args() within ipython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, argparse

I'm learning basics of Python and got already stuck at the beginning of argparse tutorial.  I'm getting the following error:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

```
usage: __main__.py [-h] echo
__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

a %tb command gives the following output:

```
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-843cc484f12f> in <module>()
----> 1 args = parser.parse_args()

C:\Users\Haik\Anaconda2\lib\argparse.pyc in parse_args(self, args, namespace)
   1702         if argv:
   1703             msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
-> 1704             self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
   1705         return args
   1706 

C:\Users\Haik\Anaconda2\lib\argparse.pyc in error(self, message)
   2372         """
   2373         self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
-> 2374         self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))

C:\Users\Haik\Anaconda2\lib\argparse.pyc in exit(self, status, message)
   2360         if message:
   2361             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
-> 2362         _sys.exit(status)
   2363 
   2364     def error(self, message):

SystemExit: 2
```

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: You cannot experiment with this easily in ipython as the ipython command line will be used per default in `parse_args`. Try this with a normal `*.py` file and the python executable to launch that file.

Comment: See this [argparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714542/why-does-pythons-argparse-use-an-error-code-of-2-for-systemexit). It will help to you or surely helps to others

Comment: I've reproduced your code and I don't find any problem. Have you tried it in .py file instead of another way?

Comment: Alternatively in ipython you can pass a list of args to the parser. From the argparse documentation: `parser.parse_args(['--sum', '7', '-1', '42'])` or `parser.parse_args('--sum 7 -1 42'.split() )`

Comment: thank you guys for immediate help pointing out where my mistake was and also providing alternative way, I've tried in different ways but all with ipython and not "normal" *.py

Comment: Please check out my answer below. I spent 3 hours on this and I think I found the real solution (and it should be the accepted answer to help people with the same problem). I took my answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796169/how-to-fix-ipykernel-launcher-py-error-unrecognized-arguments-in-jupyter

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`argparse` is a module designed to parse the arguments passed from the **command line**, so for example if you type the following at a command prompt:

```
$ python my_programme.py --arg1=5 --arg2=7
```

You can use `argparse` to interpret the `--arg1=5 --arg2=7` part. If `argparse` thinks the arguments are invalid, it exits, which in general is done in python by calling `sys.exit()` which raises the `SystemExit` error, which is what you're seeing.

So the problem is you're trying to use `argparse` from an interactive interpreter (looks like ipython), and at this point the programme has already started, so the args should have already been parsed.

To try it properly create a separate python file such as `my_programme.py` and run it using `python` from a command line, as I illustrated.

Comment: yes it was exactly ipython, just want to say how much i appreciate your clear answer! And even I've spent several hours trying to figure out it myself, it seems I would need some more days to solve this problem alone. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

[*quick solution*] Add an dummy parser argument in the code

```py
parser.add_argument('-f')
```

Comment: Hey, it worked but can you please provide some explanation on how does it working?

Comment: Jupyter-Notebook has some some default arguments set. One of which is "-f ".

import sys
sys.argv

running the above code will display them

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. The accepted answer is not a solution, my code is a Jupyter notebook I cannot run it as a script in the command line.

Answer (score 26):

had run into a similar issue. adding these lines fixed the issue for me.

```
import sys
sys.argv=['']
del sys
```

Comment: Umm... why did that help? Can you explain this for anyone that comes reading it?

Comment: Helpful answer, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771872/5137827

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned this answer here [How to fix ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments in jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796169/how-to-fix-ipykernel-launcher-py-error-unrecognized-arguments-in-jupyter)

There is no need for the `-f` argument. Also, the `-f` trick works for Jupyter but not in VS code.

tl;dr

Use

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

INSTEAD of

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 5):

`parse_args` method, when it's called without arguments, attempts to parse content of `sys.argv`. Your interpreter process had filled `sys.argv` with values that does not match with arguments supported by your `parser` instance, that's why parsing fails.

Try printing `sys.argv` to check what arguments was passed to your interpreter process.

Try calling `parser.parse_args(['my', 'list', 'of', 'strings'])` to see how parser will work for interpreter launched with different cmdline arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Use `get_ipython().__class__.__name__` to determine whether we're running on ipython or terminal, and then use `parser.parse_args(args = [])` when we're running on ipython

   ```py
   try:
       get_ipython().__class__.__name__
       # No error means we're running on ipython
       args = parser.parse_args(args = []) # Reset args
   except NameError:
       # NameError means that we're running on terminal
       args = parser.parse_args()
   ```
2. Use `parser.parse_known_args()` to store existing args separately. We would get a  return of a tuple with two values (first is args that are added by `add_argument` and second is existing args)

   ```py
   args = parser.parse_known_args()[0] # Allow unrecognized arguments
   ```

The difference of these two approaches is that the second one will allow unrecognized arguments. It will be stored in the second value of the returned tuple.

Comment: I find the second approach minimal invasive, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is nearly three years old but as dumb as it can sound, this exit error is also produced when you don't have argparse installed instead of the default "This module can't be found" error message. Just helping people that may have this error aswell.

Comment: How can it be not installed? This is a standard library module.

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument and assign some value works. I was passing args (ArgumentParser type object) from one function to another (not in a typical case, like, getting user args from terminal).

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
# create and assign a dummy args
parser.add_argument('--myarg1')
args = parser.parse_args(['--myarg1', ''])

args.myarg2 = True  # actuals args assignment
myTargetFunction(args)  # passing args to another function
```

I found without any actual args in parser, parse_args() gives error.