# How to fix ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments in jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am following this tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started_for_beginners) after two days setting up the environment I finally could run `premade_estimator.py` using cmd

[image]

but when I try to run the same code in a jupyter notebook I am getting this error:

> ```
> usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE]
>                              [--train_steps TRAIN_STEPS]
>
> ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-4faecb24-6e87-40b4-bf15-5d24520d7130.json
> ```
>
> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> ```
> SystemExit: 2
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\python3x\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2918: 
> UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D. warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
> ```

I have tried to fix it without success using:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade jupyter

pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install

conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernelspec install-self
```

Any idea will be appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got it! the reason why we get the error is because this code is using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and this module is used to write user-friendly command-line interfaces, so it seems, it has a conflict with Jupyter Notebook.

I found the solution in this [page](https://qiita.com/LittleWat/items/6e56857e1f97c842b261):

What we have to do is:

Delete or comment these lines:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=100, type=int, help='batch size')
parser.add_argument('--train_steps', default=1000, type=int,
                    help='number of training steps')
```

and replace `args`

```
args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
```

for a dictionary using the library [`easydict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easydict/) in this way:

```
args = easydict.EasyDict({
    "batch_size": 100,
    "train_steps": 1000
})
```

With `easydict` we can access dict values as attributes for the arguments.

**Update**

After all this year diving deeper in python, I found the solution for this question is way more simple (We don't need to use any external library or method). `argparse` is just one of the many ways to pass arguments to a script in python from the terminal. When I tried to do it in a jupyter notebook obviously that wasn't going to work. We can just replace in the function directly the parameters like:

```
funtion(batch_size=100, train_steps=1000)
```

Now, if we have a long list of parameters for our function, we can use `*args` or `**kargs`.

`*args` pass a tuple as parameters in the function, for this case, in particular, it will be:

```
args = (100, 1000)
function(*args)
```

`**kargs` pass a dictionary as arguments to our function:

```
kargs = {"batch_size": 100,
        "train_steps": 1000}
function(**kargs)
```

just google it and you will find a really good explanation on how to use them both, here one [documentation](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) that I used to study this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Encountered the same problem and this post helped me resolve it.

Comment: Or just use `parser.parse_args(args=[])`, because `parse_args()` will pass `_sys.argv[1:]` as `args`'s default parameter, replace it with empty list `[]` solve this problem.

Answer (score 74):

A more elegant solution would be:

```
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

instead of

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: This answer solves the args parse problem in Jupyter like a charm!   But could you please explain a little bit? Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

I just ran into this problem today and found a quick, stupid solution is to insert an argument processor for the `-f` argument that qtconsole/ipython passes though and we did not expect. At end of `parser.add_argument` I put in:

```
parser.add_argument("-f", "--fff", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
```

I don't use the `-f` parameter, so there's no loss for me.

I'd rather not re-engineer a larger argument processing framework just because of ipython cropping up in workflow on one particular computer...

Comment: :)) thank U for the simple and funny solution man. It worked for me.

Comment: Solved the dumb ipykerner_launcher bug when using argparse in Colab. Kudos!!
(Some heroes don't wear cape. They just code!)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@data.scientist/ipython-trick-how-to-use-argparse-in-ipython-notebooks-a07423ab31fc) is passing empty string to the `parse_args` method.

For instance:

```py
import argparse


def arguments():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example')
  
  return parser.parse_args("")
```

The above solution actually works in google-colab.

Comment: Thank you. `args = parser.parse_args("")` worked for me in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem with :

```
from serial.tools.list_ports import main
main()
```

but it's a library from serial import

so i make a copy in my own directory the file from :
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/tools`

and edit to add :

```
parser.add_argument("-f", "--fff", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
```

as *pauljohn32* (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086346/pauljohn32) did !

now using the new file locally:

```
from list_ports import main
main()
```

it works fine !

Comment: similarly getting error from another library (unittest mock) when calling unittest.main(), instead setup a testsuite+runner ```suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSen5xI2cDevice)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
conda install ipykernel --name Python3
python -m ipykernel install
```

Comment: I just tried and it showed me: `All requested packages already installed.`

Comment: Have you also upgraded the kernel? pip install --upgrade ipykernel

Comment: Yes I did, I am reading the documentation for `argparse` to see if there is the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to run the premade_estimator.py from a jupyter notebook or are you copying the script contents to a cell in the notebook?

Comment: @MiltonArangoG I am copying the script contents to a cell in a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Python's **argparse** module is typically used for handling command line arguments in a Python script. When you run a script from the command line, you can provide arguments that the script uses to customize its behavior. However, *argparse* doesn't work in a Jupyter notebook (or a Google Colab Project) because notebooks aren't run from the command line, so there are no command line arguments for *argparse* to parse. If you have a script that uses *argparse* and you want to run it in a notebook, you'll have to find a different way to provide the arguments.

I used the **Namespace** module like this:

```
from argparse import Namespace

args = Namespace(
    retriever="bm25",
    index_path="indexes/lucene-index.enwiki-20180701-paragraphs",
    k1=1.2, 
    b=0.75, 
    language="english"
)
searcher = build_searcher(args)
```

The **argparse.Namespace** class in Python is a simple 'holder' object for attributes. This class is typically used for command line argument parsing. The parsed arguments are then stored as attributes within a Namespace object.

A Namespace object can be thought of as an object where you can add attributes dynamically. It is like a Python dictionary, but instead of using the bracket notation `my_dict["key"]`, you can use the dot notation `my_namespace.key` for example like this:

```
args = Namespace(name="Alice", age=25)
print(args.name)
print(args.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error for many more "unrecognized arguments":
`ipykernel_launcher: error: unrecognized arguments: --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"2dd531d9" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=tmp-18240vZXCSGIbxxcJ.json An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.`

For each unrecognized argument (i.e ip, stdin, control, ..), I added a line to add the argument to my ArgParser (as suggested by @pauljohn32):

```
        ap.add_argument(
            "-i", "--ip", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-s", "--stdin", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-c", "--control", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-b", "--hb", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-K", "--Session.key", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-S", "--Session.signature_scheme", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-l", "--shell", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-t", "--transport", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
        ap.add_argument(
            "-o", "--iopub", help="a dummy argument to fool ipython", default="1")
```

Answer (score 0):

> because this code is using argparse and this module is used to write user-friendly command-line interfaces, so it seems, it has a conflict with Jupyter Notebook.

the reason is as above, but I think it is better to convert args to class than to dict as @virtualdvid and @Hrvoje said

```
class args_:
 self.batch_size = 100,
 self.train_steps = 1000
args = args_
```