# Google API: Why can't it find my file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api

So I am trying to use the Google Drive API, but I keep running into an error (Cannot access credentials.json: No such file or directory).  I looked up what someone else did and they solved it by using an absolute file path.  I tried this by making:

```
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

Into:

```
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(r'C:\Users\FIEND\Documents\Google Sheets Script\client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

Both of these got this error:

```
C:\Users\FIEND\AnacondaTests\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py:255: 
UserWarning: Cannot access credentials.json: No such file or directory
warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                         [--noauth_local_webserver]
                         [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT 
...]]]
                         [--logging_level 
{DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f 
C:\Users\FIEND\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-aa1a9ef5-446a-46d0- 
b6fb-032bd6d673e7.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2


C:\Users\FIEND\AnacondaTests\lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2918: UserWarning: To exit: use 
'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
 warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Here is the rest of the code for reference:

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Sheets API. Prints values from a Google 
Spreadsheet.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
# Call the Sheets API
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                         range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    print('Name, Major:')
    for row in values:
        # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))
```

**Edit**

Making an empty credentials.json file cleared most of the errors, but I am still getting an "error: unrecognized arguments".

Full error text:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [--auth_host_name 
AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                         [--noauth_local_webserver]
                         [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT 
[AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                         [--logging_level 
{DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f 
C:\Users\FIEND\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel- 
c568600c-15a8-4f33-a635-409e218e40bf.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an empty configuration.json file. [Github Google Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python/issues/6).

Please follow the following setup steps to get the authentication properly.

> Step 1: Turn on the Drive API
>
> 1. Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials.
> 2. On the Add credentials to your project page, click the Cancel button.
> 3. At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click the Save button.
> 4. Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.
> 5. Select the application type Other, enter the name "Drive API Quickstart", and click the Create button.
> 6. Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.
> 7. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
> 8. Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python

**UPDATE**

Apparently, there is a conflict between argparse and Jupyter [[Reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798075/4626495)

and oauth2client is using argparse [Github Code Link](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/2da8ccde3f74507990cb551fe48f6d25820e6ab3/oauth2client/tools.py#L82)

I have not used Jupyter myself, but if you can, try using your google drive api code independently without Jupyter.

Comment: Hey, thanks @x899, creating the empty configuration.jason file, helped clear most of the errors.  Unfortuanately I am still getting "error: unrecognized arguments".

Answer (score 0):

just copy your credential file and paste in the same folder in the c drive.