# Python create exe file error

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, py2exe

I'm trying to create a exe file from my .py file but using both, *PYINSTALLER* and *PY2EXE* gives me a strange error:

[image: create EXE error]

The *google.py* file that I'm tying to create EXE existis in the requested directory and both PYINSTALLER and PY2EXE are correctlly installed.

Does anyone know the root cause of the issue? How could I create a exe file from a .PY?

Comment: Did you do anythign differently than e.g. described in this tutorial? http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50093977/4996248 The fact that you are getting the exact same error message with two different modules suggests that those modules are not the problem. The problem seems to be related to the Google Drive API, which you seem to be using.

Answer (score 2):

As I know you must use argument `--onefile` Without it the libraries will be distributed as separate file along with the executable.
Here is exaple:

`pyinstaller --onefile script.py`

Comment: I still having the same error: >pyinstaller --onefile google.py
usage: pyinstaller-script.py [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                             [--noauth_local_webserver]
                             [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                             [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
pyinstaller-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --onefile google.py

Comment: Is your script - google.py located in the same directory as pyinstaller?

Comment: @maxrt is right. The script should be in the same directory as pyinstaller and by looking at the command window it doesn't look like it is in the same directory.