# error: unrecognized arguments: - pytorch code in colab

Tags: pytorch, argparse, google-colaboratory

I tried to run my code on google **colab**. but I get this message (`error: unrecognized arguments`)when I'm trying to call this function :

```
def parse_opts():
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument(
     '--root_path',
     default='/root/data/ActivityNet',
     type=str,
     help='Root directory path of data')
  parser.add_argument(
     '--video_path',
     default='video_kinetics_jpg',
     type=str,
     help='Directory path of Videos')
 args = parser.parse_args()

return args
```

but this is failed and I get this error

> tester_video.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
>   cifar_comp_20_200_0.01_0.1 20 10 0.01 0.1

I tried to use **Easydict** but it seems its not working
thinks

Comment: Your code expects just two arguments, `--root_path` and `--video_path`, so you either need to extend it to accommodate other arguments or just call it with two arguments, i.e. the root and the video path.

Comment: this is not the full function, it contains more arguments. if i run this on my own CPU it works fine, but when i load it to google colaboratory for run this code on the GPU it doesn't works..

Comment: Do those unrecognized arguments look like something you used in calling the script, that is, part of your command line?  What does the `sys.argv` look like?  Maybe those strings are meant for the `colab` environment, not your script.

Comment: this arguments read correctly by the command line, i checked this. this is somehow fall in the google colab when im using "argparse". my problem is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796169/how-to-fix-ipykernel-launcher-py-error-unrecognized-arguments-in-jupyter

Answer (score 5):

The problem only appears in Jupyter notebook/lab/colab.

Change

`args = parser.parse_args()`

to

`args = parser.parse_args(args=[])`

and it should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem. you need to use easydict instead of argparse.
insted of the code above you can write this:

```
args = easydict.EasyDict(
{
    "root_path": '/root/data/ActivityNet',
    "video_path": 'video_kinetics_jpg',
    "annotation_path": 'kinetics.json',
    "result_path": 'results',
    "dataset": 'kinetics',
    "n_classes": 400,
    "n_finetune_classes": 400,
    "sample_size": 64,
    "sample_duration": 32,
    "initial_scale": 1.0,
    "n_scales": 5,
    "scale_step": 0.84089641525,
    "train_crop": 'corner',
    "learning_rate": 0.1 )}
```