# Regression with hyperparameter optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to solve a time-series regression problem with `pytorch` and using `optuna` to do the hyperparameter optimization. I have tried to adapt [this example](https://github.com/optuna/optuna-examples/blob/main/pytorch/pytorch_lightning_simple.py) in the optuna docs which aims to do hand-written digit recognition.

I've customized the `setup` function in the `FashionMNISTDataModule` class so that it accepts my pandas dataframe:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
...

class FashionMNISTDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    
    ...

    def setup(self, stage: Optional[str] = None) -> None:

        #self.mnist_test = datasets.FashionMNIST(
        #    self.data_dir, train=False, download=0, transform=transforms.ToTensor()
        #)
        #mnist_full = datasets.FashionMNIST(
        #    self.data_dir, train=True, download=0, transform=transforms.ToTensor()
        #)

        # inputs
        X = df[['x1','x2','x3','x4']]

        # output
        y = df[['y']]

        # separate into training/testing data
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=500)

        # convert to tensors
        X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train.to_numpy()).float()
        y_train = torch.squeeze(torch.from_numpy(y_train.to_numpy()).float())
        X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test.to_numpy()).float()
        y_test = torch.squeeze(torch.from_numpy(y_test.to_numpy()).float())

        self.mnist_test = X_test
        mnist_full = y_test

        self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, [55000, 5000])

    ...
```

My example data is:

```
>> df

                    y       x1        x2         x3      x4  
Date                                                          
2018-03-05   73.68750   2204.0  108.6875   5.964844  2018.0   
2018-03-12   65.06250   2244.0  106.0000  11.164062  2102.0   
2018-03-19   61.28125   2240.0  106.8750   8.304688  2130.0   
2018-03-26   57.87500   2256.0  107.5625  16.750000  2154.0   
2019-03-04  173.37500   1826.0  113.8125  16.328125  2130.0   
2019-03-11  199.75000   1789.0  110.3750   6.386719  2038.0   
2019-03-18  206.25000   1809.0  109.6250   4.468750  1958.0   
2019-03-25  186.50000   1780.0  111.1875  17.375000  1949.0   
2020-03-02   63.81250   2586.0  113.2500   8.281250  2108.0   
2020-03-09   52.75000   2514.0  111.6875  12.937500  2088.0   
2020-03-16   72.12500   2468.0  109.7500  15.960938  2058.0   
2020-03-23   75.87500   2394.0  111.0000  18.890625  2023.0   
2020-03-30   51.71875   2298.0   95.1250  10.843750  2122.0
```

If I run the code with my new function (keeping everything else nearly the same), I get an error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--pruning]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /home/<username>/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-027f206b-6952-4ff2-bdbe-c947aad00191.json

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

It might be because I'm trying to pass a tensor into a function that doesn't accept tensors, but I'm not sure what to change.

If I run the code via .py file instead of on jupyterlab, I get the error message

```
ValueError('Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optuna\_optimize.py", line 216, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\mymodel_v12beta.py", line 169, in objective
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=datamodule)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 458, in fit
    self._run(model)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 713, in _run
    self.call_setup_hook(model)  # allow user to setup lightning_module in accelerator environment
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1159, in call_setup_hook
    self.datamodule.setup(stage=fn)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\datamodule.py", line 384, in wrapped_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\mymodel_v12beta.py", line 129, in setup
    self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, [10, 3])
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py", line 332, in random_split
    raise ValueError("Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!")
ValueError: Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset! [0m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\mymodel_v12beta.py", line 190, in <module>
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100, timeout=600)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optuna\study.py", line 401, in optimize
    _optimize(
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optuna\_optimize.py", line 65, in _optimize
    _optimize_sequential(
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optuna\_optimize.py", line 162, in _optimize_sequential
    trial = _run_trial(study, func, catch)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optuna\_optimize.py", line 267, in _run_trial
    raise func_err
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\optuna\_optimize.py", line 216, in _run_trial
    value_or_values = func(trial)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\mymodel_v12beta.py", line 169, in objective
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=datamodule)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 458, in fit
    self._run(model)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 713, in _run
    self.call_setup_hook(model)  # allow user to setup lightning_module in accelerator environment
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1159, in call_setup_hook
    self.datamodule.setup(stage=fn)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\datamodule.py", line 384, in wrapped_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\mymodel_v12beta.py", line 129, in setup
    self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, [10, 3])
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py", line 332, in random_split
    raise ValueError("Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!")
ValueError: Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to refer to a parser argument conflicting with the use of jupyter notebook.

Did you try to run it on command line (with a .py file instead of notebook) ?

You may try some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796169/how-to-fix-ipykernel-launcher-py-error-unrecognized-arguments-in-jupyter)

Comment: Thanks, I tried again in a .py file and get the error `ValueError: Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!`

Comment: Do you have the full error ? Especially the reference to the line.

I think that it may be this line :
        self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, [55000, 5000])

You're not using the fashionmnist dataset anymore so the values are wrong. You have to calculate them beforehand.

Also I am not sure it was your goal to use mnist_full here as it's only the targets.
It might be better to split your train set to train and validation like how you did before with the train_test_split() function.

Comment: I added the error message to my post. I tried to change the `self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, ...)` to account for my dataset dimensions but get the same error.

Comment: So mnist_full = y_test which is of size 0.2*13 so 2 or 3 depending on the code behind. So your split [10,3] is still wrong I think.   
Can you try :  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=500)  
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=500)   
Then do the transform to tensor and affectation to self.mnist_ for train, val and test