# How to argparse() in Google Colab? (TensorFlowOnSpark application)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pyspark, google-colaboratory, argparse

In Google Colab notebook, I'm developing a project in which I try to scale up my Keras sequential model into Pyspark environment.

1. At first I developed and tested a CNN model that classifies real faces and comics faces from a Kaggle dataset (2 folders with 20.000 .jpg files). The zip file can be downloaded here: "! kaggle datasets download -d defileroff/comic-faces-paired-synthetic-v2"
2. Secondly I converted the CNN model in a tf.estimator and followed all the steps from the guide (https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/wiki/Conversion-Guide) in order to sun my estimator in Pyspark.

The the estimator works correctly until I try to introduce it in a TFParallel.run(**kargs) command for which a previous argparse() function is required.

The error I recieve is:
*"usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--cluster_size CLUSTER_SIZE]
[--num_ps NUM_PS] [--tensorboard]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-7aa3f316-ee26-49e8-9d72-7814d9a48255.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2"*

It looks like there is a problem with argparse() function.

Very Briefly, the code is available here (https://colab.research.google.com/github/cosimo-schiavoni/Massive_Data_Project/blob/main/Downloads_TFOS_ERROR.ipynb) and the structure is:

#Import Libraries
...

#def inference function: the function takes all the code indented, including the TFParallel() command.

```
def inference(): 





if __name__ == '__main__':
  #Start Spark session and context
  spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Pyspark on Google Colab")
  sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf().setAppName("TFOS"))
  conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Colab")
  executors = sc._conf.get("spark.executor.instances")
  #Define parameters to parse
  num_executors = int(executors) if executors is not None else 1
  num_ps=1

  #Define Parser
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--cluster_size", help="number of nodes in the cluster (for Spark 
  Standalone)", type=int, default=num_executors)
  parser.add_argument("--num_ps", help="number of parameter servers", type=int, 
  default=num_ps)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  #define the CNN Keras sequential model and compile it.
  cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

  ...

  cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

  #Convert the CNN model in a tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate
  from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
  # create generator object
  datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  rescale=1./255,
  validation_split=0.2)

  #define train test input function
  @tf.function     
  def train_input_fn():
  val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(
  ...)
  return features, labels
    
  #define validation test input function
  @tf.function 
  def eval_input_fn():
    val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    ...)
    return features, labels

  #define the estimator
  import tempfile
  model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  keras_estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
  keras_model=cnn, model_dir=model_dir)

#Train and evaluate the estimator
  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=1000)
  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

  tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(keras_estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

  #define parallel run of estimator in Spark environment
  
 #TFCluster.run(sc,main_fun,args,args.cluster_size,args.num_ps,TFCluster.InputMode.TENSORFLOW)
  TFParallel.run(sc, inference, args, args.cluster_size, use_barrier=False)
```

#call inference function and activate the code

```
inference()
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Moreover I have doubts about the configuration of Spark Session, is it correctly configured?
Is there a way tho knwow if I have a cluster or just a single device?
Can I know the number of active workers?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The notebook you have attached does not open however this error occures because the code is using`argparse`and this module is used to write user-friendly command-line interfaces, so it seems, it has a conflict with Jupyter Notebook. You can refer to this [article](https://qiita.com/LittleWat/items/6e56857e1f97c842b261) which provides the solution. Basically the `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()` line needs to be commented along with the `parser.add_argument()` lines. Then replace args using easydict library. Similar issue has been resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796169)