# Why I am getting this error: TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I am facing problems with the argparse library.

I have the encodings.pickle file and I am following the below code to recognize the actors but it seems to load the embeddings is not working.

Here is the code:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
                help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
                help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
ap.add_argument("-fnn", "--fast-nn", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args('')
print(args)

# load the known faces and embeddings
print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())
```

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/divya21raj/Actor-Recognition-In-Movies/blob/master/faceRecVideo.py).

Answer (score 7):

You are getting this error because the `parse_args()` method returns a Namespace containing the parsed arguments.

When printing the result of that method, you will see the created namespace: `Namespace(encodings='encoding', image='image', detection_method='cnn', fast_nn=False)`

In order to access arguments, you should use dot notation (i.e. `args.encodings` or `args.image`)

Amended code:

```py
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
                help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
                help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
ap.add_argument("-fnn", "--fast-nn", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

# load the known faces and embeddings
print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args.encodings, "rb").read())
```

Comment: still facing the same error. 
could you please clarify by amending the above code? I am afraid if I have missed somrthing.

Comment: Amended @AhmedAbousari.

Comment: the parser was not defined so I did the following:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

Comment: when I amend the code to:
args = parser.parse_args('')
I got the below error:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'encodings'
but if I made like your code without (''): 
args = parser.parse_args()
I got the below error: 
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. SystemExit: 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249982/systemexit-2-error-when-calling-parse-args-within-ipython @AhmedAbousari