# deep_learning_keras, Spacy Example, SystemExit:2 running in Jupyter/Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spacy

My overall aim is to run the Deep_Learning_keras which is a SpaCy example in Google Colab (ie in Jupyter Notebooks)

The GitHub link to the Deep_Learning_keras SpaCy example is:https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/deep_learning_keras.py

When I ran the example code directly in Google Colab I got the following error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-r] [-H 64] [-L 100] [-d 0.5] [-e 0.001]
[-i 5] [-b 256] [-n -1][model_dir] [train_dir] [dev_dir]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

I understand that the example was originally written for python and that running the copy in a Jupyter Notebook environment is not entirely compatible. I'm not sure what code/statements I need to change in the example to make it compatible

I did a google search for the SystemExit: 2 error and the closest example I found was (however the problem within the SystemExit: 2 is different to my problem):

[SystemExit: 2 error when calling parse_args() in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000428/systemexit-2-error-when-calling-parse-args-in-ipython-notebook)

Thanks